# Best method of connecting to a ubuntu server from windows and having file transfer abilities

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a personal ubuntu server that I would like to remotely connect to from my Windows 10 PC. I need to be able to transfer files to and from it as well.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For connection and file transfer:

- SSH connection (possibly with authentication key) from Windows to the Ubuntu, using a SSH client on Windows (PuTTY, WinSCP)(Filezilla can also use SFTP). For file transfer you can access all the files that your connection user is allowed to, wherever they are. SSH only gives you a basic terminal, but if you need to use Ubuntu-based graphics application, you can use SSH tunneling on the X session, with a XWindows server running on Windows.

For file transfer only (restricted to explicitly shared directories):

- FTP server on your Ubuntu and FTP client (Filezilla or else) on Windows
- Samba share on Ubuntu, accessed like a network share on Windows.

There is no absolute "best" way, there is a more suitable way depending on your usage profile.